# Practicing defining Classes and Methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having the following error "Line 46: undefined local variable or method `app1' for main:Object (NameError)" when I run the following Ruby code about Methods and Classes on the compiler.Thanks in advance :D!!

```
class Apps
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def add_app
       "#{name} has been added to the App Center.Approval is pending!!"
    end

    def app_approved
       "#{name} has been approved by the App Center"
    end

    def app_posted
       "Congratulations!!!!#{name} has been posted to the App Store."
    end
end

class Fbapps
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @apps = []
    end

    def add_new(a_app)
       @apps << a_app
       "#{@app} has been added to the #{@apps} store!!"
    end

    def weekly_release
       @apps.each do |app|
       puts @app
       end

       @apps.each do |app|
       app.add_app
       app.app_approved
       app.app_posted
       end
    end
end

apps = ["Bitstrip", "Candy Crush" , "Instapaper"]

apps = Fbapps.new("Apps")
apps.add_new(app1)
apps.add_new(app2)
apps.add_new(app3)
puts apps.weekly_release

app1 = Apps.new("Bitstrip")
app2 = Apps.new("Candy Crush")
app3 = Apps.new("Instapaper")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `app1`, `app2`, and `app3` before adding them to `apps`:

```
apps = ["Bitstrip", "Candy Crush" , "Instapaper"]

app1 = Apps.new("Bitstrip")
app2 = Apps.new("Candy Crush")
app3 = Apps.new("Instapaper")

apps = Fbapps.new("Apps")
apps.add_new(app1)
apps.add_new(app2)
apps.add_new(app3)
puts apps.weekly_release
```

As noted there are other bugs in your classes, but they should be relatively trivial to fix given changing the order of execution as above.

**Update**:  Here's your code updated to fix most of the bugs:

```
class Apps
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def add_app
    "#{name} has been added to the App Center.Approval is pending!!"
  end

  def app_approved
    "#{name} has been approved by the App Center"
  end

  def app_posted
    "Congratulations!!!!  #{name} has been posted to the App Store."
  end
end

class Fbapps
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @apps = []
  end

  def add_new(a_app)
    @apps << a_app
    "#{a_app.name} has been added to the #{self.name} store!!"
  end

  def weekly_release
    @apps.each do |app|
      puts app.name
    end

    @apps.each do |app|
      puts app.add_app
      puts app.app_approved
      puts app.app_posted
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit: This definitely fixes the error the question is about.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: You posted a whole lot of code with little to no explanation. As a question-and-answer site, most regular SO users tend to prefer answers like "This is wrong because X and you can fix it by doing Y" rather than "Here is a load of code. Enjoy!" Answers are generally more educational than code dumps.

Comment: Thanks @CDub for your answer.I did as you explained above.I'm getting the following output:nil
nil
nil
#<Apps:0x401be6cc>
#<Apps:0x401be6a4>
#<Apps:0x401be67c>

Comment: Thanks everybody in advance.I'm new here.So, let me know if I'm making "Rookie Mistakes":D!!

Comment: No problem man.  Sorry for the bickering back and forth between us - I guess we all have bad days from time to time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do `apps.add_new(app1)` before you define `app1`. That line needs to go *after* `app1 = Apps.new("Bitstrap")` .

Comment: I'm getting the following:nil
    nil
    nil
    Apps:0x401be6f4
    Apps:0x401be6cc
    Apps:0x401be6a4